# How to update time in mySql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update time in mysql database using php on clicking of button. I am using the following query:

```
update tableName SET Time=CURTIME() where Uname='$uname1' AND Password = '$password'
```

This query is not working. But If I hard code this query, this will work fine. I am not getting any idea about this why Its not working. Here is my complete php code :

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$uname='root';
$pwd='password';
$db='database';

$con=mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("database selection failed");

$uname1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Uname']); # Secure the input!
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Password']);
$time = strtotime(exec("date"));

$flag['code']=0;

$select=("update Insert1 SET Time=CURTIME() where Uname='$uname1' AND BINARY Password = BINARY '$password'" );
//$select=("select * from Insert1 where Uname = '$uname1' AND BINARY Password = BINARY '$password'" );

$r=mysql_query($select,$con);

if(mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) { 
   $flag['code']=1;
}
print(json_encode($flag));
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with "NOW()" instead of "CURTIME()" in the update query, like this:

```
$select=("update Insert1 SET Time=NOW() where Uname='$uname1' AND BINARY Password = BINARY '$password'" );
```